# Custom Printer for Hash Table

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Is there a way to define a custom printer for hash tables in lisp, such that if you output them, their contents are clearly displayed?

I have seen some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898967/common-lisp-library-for-pretty-printing-e-g-pretty-print-a-nested-hash-table), where you can call a function to print a hash table, but I'm more interested in cases where you have hash tables embedded in structure fields. When I print the structure, I want the fields to automatically print the hash table readably without me needing to call the hash table printer after the fact.

Comment: Once you have defined the method as in the accept answer, any hash table will be printed with its content without the need of calling any function.

Comment: There's also the rutils utility: https://github.com/vseloved/rutils/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#rutilshash-table It allows to create a hash-table with `#h` and it has a switch to pretty-print them.